# Find FILE path relative to the htdocs directory

Tags: php, path

I have a script which displays the images present on a folder.
E.g. Script path (from HTDOCS):

```
/admin/global/thisscript.php
```

E.g. Pictures folder path (from HTDOCS):

```
/public/test/images/
```

Now I need to print under each image the path of the file starting from the HTDOCS directory.
E.g. if I have:

```
$picture1 = /WEB/mysite/htdocs/public/test/images/picture1.png
$picture1name = basename($picture1)
```

I'd like to print

```
print "/public/test/images/".$picture1name
```

having

```
/public/test/images
```

in a variable which is automatically update if picture1.png path changes.

If I use

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

it returns the path of the file I'm displaing. Also

```
__FILE__
__DIR__
basename
dirname
```

are not working for me.

How can I get the path?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

edit:

Something like:

```
$path = "/WEB/mysite/htdocs/public/test/images/picture1.png";
$path = dirname(str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $path));
```

Comment: I get the HTDOCS path not the path of the pictures starting from the HTDOCS folder

Comment: Gotcha, You would probably need to do something yourself then. Like str_replace the document root and dirname() to get rid of the filename.

Comment: Ok with your example is perfect

Comment: The document root variable would still point to the document root. If you already have the path to the image, doing a str_replace to remove the document root would still work.

Comment: How can I get the full path to the image withouth setting it manually in $path?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this could help but could you explode the path result you have and build it back from the HTDOCS entry? something like:

```
$fullpath = /WEB/mysite/htdocs/public/test/images/picture1.png    
$pathbits = explode("/", $fullpath);

    $newpath = "";
    $foundstart = false;

foreach($pathbits as $key => $value){ 

            if ($value == "htdocs" || $foundstart == true) {
              $foundstart = true;
              $newpath = $newpath + "/" + $value;
        } 
}
```